# mousemove triggers more often with console open?

Tags: javascript

I'm experiencing something weird, but I'm not sure if it's intended or what's causing it.

I'm experimenting with some JavaScript that loops through a set of images when the user moves the mouse across the screen. I'm using jQuery `mousemove` for this. Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sy35dzeh/1/

The behaviour I'm experiencing is some kind of throttle with the mouse movement. I want every pixel moved to increment the `pixelCount` variable. But when moving the mouse in longer sweeps, it seems like the iteration reaches a limit. This causes the counter to increment faster when moving the mouse slowly as there are more "pixels" per movement added. I get that this might be how `mousemove` works, but on top of that it behaves differently when opening the developer tools.

When I open the developer tools in Chrome as try to move the mouse again, the iteration is a lot more rapid. This is the behaviour I want, when the iteration becomes slower on slower mouse movement and faster when moving the mouse faster.

Here's a video of the difference:
https://streamable.com/okqql3

Any idea why it's different when I open the console and any idea how to make the mouse movement affect the iteration in the way I want it to behave (like when I have the developer tools open)?

Comment: If you remove jquery from the picture entirely I would expect it to be more accurate as an [example here](https://codepen.io/chris-w/pen/ZNzXBQ)

Comment: Still have the same behaviour after using vanilla JavaScript: https://jsfiddle.net/jgzkt5b6/

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I sped read your question before! You're talking about the coordinate skipping! That's a by design hardware limitation, you'll want to do [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13105366/how-to-precisely-track-the-mouse-cordinates-without-skips) instead. Sorry about that!

Comment: No worries! I could imagine that this is something done "by design", or at least that it was caused by a limitation with the `mousemove` event. Strange though however that the mouse is not skipping, at least not as much, when having developer tools open.

The link you sent is for C#. But maybe there are similar methods for doing this in JavaScript.

Comment: Ah ya sorry again haha too much multi tasking today, basically it just doesn't report it fast enough so if you move it fast enough you miss the updated values since it's not emitting the updated value fast enough since in the time the event is bubbling the coord could already be changed. Especially at a javascript browser level. I don't have an answer for that one off the top of my head with javascript UIEvent interface.

Comment: On that note, definitely a +1 for this question, would love to know myself also!

Comment: I experience the same issue with the pointermove event. With developer tools closed, it seems laggy, but much more smooth when open. Any solution to decrease interations time ?

Comment: Video of the pb (sorry in french)
https://www.loom.com/share/429e8647c1ec460d88d73d6ab124e5c6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by using `event.getCoalescedEvents()` which get the missing "in between" movements.
Note that you need to listen for "pointermove", which I was doing in my case.

```
 this.canvas.addEventListener('pointermove', this.onMouseMove.bind(this), { passive: true });

 onMouseMove(event) {
    const events = event.getCoalescedEvents();
    for (let i = 0; i < events.length; i++) this.onMovement(events[i]);
  }

  onMovement(event) {
    // standard processing
  }
```

Comment: I withdraw my bounty

Comment: One comment though is that I’m unsure of how wide the support for getCoalescedEvents is. Seems like it’s not working on Safari with iOS 14.8.1 at least, trying this example: https://omwnk.codesandbox.io, but that’s not a big deal in my scenario.

Answer (score 1):

[Mousemove event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousemove_event) is not called for every pixel, but it works like this - [the browser periodically checks the cursor position](https://javascript.info/mousemove-mouseover-mouseout-mouseenter-mouseleave#skipping-elements) and, noticing changes, generates `mousemove` events.
Accordingly, in your case, it is better not to count pixels from the number of event triggers, but the difference in coordinate changes is needed.

Also, when calling `mousemove`, I do not recommend using slow and heavy synchronous functions and it is worth adding them separately to the [Event Loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) (at least through `setTimeout`).

Below I have slightly modified the example you specified:

```js
let imageIndex = 1
let pixelCount = 0
let $targetElement = $(".mouse-image");
let divisions = 50

let pixelThreshold = Math.floor($(window).width() / divisions)

$(document).ready(function() {
  $targetElement.eq(0).addClass("is-active");
})

$(window).on("resize", function() {
  pixelThreshold = Math.floor($(window).width() / divisions)
})
let prevX = null;
let prevY = null;
let timeout = null;
$(document).on("mouseenter", function(ev) {
  prevX = ev.clientX;
  prevY = ev.clientY;
})

$(document).on("mouseleave", function(ev) {
  prevX = null;
  prevY = null;
})

$(document).on("mousemove", function(ev) {
  const posX = ev.clientX;
  const posY = ev.clientY;
  const deltaX = (!prevX) ? 1 : Math.abs(posX - prevX);
  const deltaY = (!prevY) ? 1 : Math.abs(posY - prevY);
  prevX = posX;
  prevY = posY;
  pixelCount += (deltaX + deltaY);

  if (pixelCount > pixelThreshold) {
    pixelCount = 0;
    changeImage();
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(changeImage, 20);
  }
  $(".debug").text(`${pixelCount}, ${pixelThreshold}`)
})

function changeImage() {
  imageIndex++
  if (imageIndex >= $targetElement.length) {
    imageIndex = 0;
  }
  $targetElement.removeClass("is-active");
  $targetElement.eq(imageIndex).addClass("is-active");
}
```

```css
html {
  font-size: 100%
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

*,
:after,
:before {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.image-container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh
}

.mouse-image {
  display: none;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}

.mouse-image.is-active {
  display: block
}

.debug {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 999999999;
  font-size: 4rem
}

.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 9999
}

.wrapper .trigger {
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="debug"></div>
<div class="image-container">
  <img class="mouse-image" src="https://www.airtasker.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Puppy-toilet-training-1200x675.jpg" alt="">
  <img class="mouse-image" src="https://awl.org.au/sites/default/files/styles/page_hero/public/hero/puppy-1221791_1920.jpg?itok=SLa7BGdj" alt="">
  <img class="mouse-image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcT69ZsF7GXUMrNLc1AOvNjXXoZWmNyA61fAqg&usqp=CAU" alt="">
  <img class="mouse-image" src="https://www.bil-jac.com/media/ww5kq5u4/puppy.jpg?anchor=center&mode=crop&width=1024&height=512" alt="">
  <img class="mouse-image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRWeA5-zFa86-P6aDd5NUERS6ay9isKpgkDiQ&usqp=CAU" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: this does not explain why it is smoother while Chrome dev tools are open

Comment: @MickaelFM, As I said, the browser periodically polls the coordinates with mousemove. And this frequency is affected by how loaded the [Event Loop](https://javascript.info/event-loop#event-loop) is (and rendering and updating the DOM directly affect this). By opening the WebInspector, you reduce the viewport, which directly affects the rendering of the page and elements. In normal cases, these are small things, but with mousemove it is noticeable.

Comment: @MickaelFM, If you need to perform synchronous calculations with mousemove, transfer them to [WebWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API). For example, if you need to perform any serious calculations with rendering in Canvas as the mouse moves, use [OffscreenCanvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OffscreenCanvas) in a separate WebWorker.